# AWS S3 not serving relative path from subfolder

Tags: amazon-s3

I've deployed a static site to an S3 bucket. All seems well (static web hosting checked, bucket properties set), expect for relative path.

For instance the following:

```
/subfolder/foo.html:
<script src="vendor/Three.min.js"></script>
```

Will result, in the browser console, in `404` for `http://my.site.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/vendor/Three.min.js/`. The `subfolder` part is missing from the URL. The actual resource `http://my.site.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/subfolder/vendor/Three.min.js/` is accessible. And if I server my site locally with python `http.server`, the js file is served as intended.

Replacing the script tag with `"./vendor/Three.min.js"` or `"./vendor/Three.min.js/"` does not help.

What am I missing in this S3 puzzler?

Comment: There must be something you're omitting from the description, because relative path resolution is done by the browser, not the server.  When viewing `example.com/subfolder/foo.html` the relative path `vendor/script.js` should resolve to `example.com/subfolder/vendor/script.js`.  S3 doesn't do anything to change that.  The trailing slash `/` at the end of your URL seems wrong, and suggests that your browser is following at least one redirect before trying to fetch that, and possibly more than one redirect.  Check that?

Comment: You're damn right; I jumped through so many hoops to make the different parts work (S3, CF, Route53...) that I missed the obvious and suspected some AWS foul play. The problem comes from the fact that the URL in the browser was `http://my.site.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/subfolder` *without trailing slash*. If you want, you can turn your comment into an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: How did you fix this @youri?

Comment: As far as I recall, I was missing a trailing slash in the source code *or* I had one too much, and the browser dev console was "lying" to me. I wanted @Michael-sqlbot to take credit for the answer therefore I did not self-answer, and now my memory of the event is fuzzy at best and it will be written on the internet until the end of times.